# How to float a fixed element that's also responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get an element to stay on the right side of the screen and not scroll. I've achieved this fine but then the text goes over my imagery on mobile, instead of beneath it, which I do not want.

Basically, I'm trying to do what is being done here:

http://newnotio.fuelthemes.net/portfolio/identity-by-versace/

I used:

```
.elementname {
position: float;
right: 0;
}
```

But I don't really know what I'm doing and seem to be missing something. Also, I have an older version of the same theme, if that helps.

Comment: you want the box on the right to stay at same point like on the site you posted or you want the box to go beneath the other box?

Comment: Hey, Hans. I'm trying to do both. In that link, it stays at the same point on desktop but when I make the window mobile-size, the box goes beneath. So I guess it's not fixed then? But I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

After looking the website, I have the solution.

**Method:** Just put the `right div` with `position fixed` and `add padding-right(= the width of the right div or more)` to the `element(s) concerned(s)`

```css
.navbar {
  background:#90A4AE;
  color:rgba(255,255,255, .75);
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  /** adding padding right width of the right bar or more if you want **/
  padding:0 60px 0 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  padding:20px;
}

.some-content {
  margin:10px 0;
  background:#B0BEC5;
/** adding padding right width of the right bar or more if you want **/
  padding:0 60px 0 0;
}

.right-bar {
  z-index:999;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  width:60px;
  display:flex;
}

.right-bar span {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example 2</li>
</div>
<div class="some-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed pretium dui. Vivamus rhoncus scelerisque risus eu accumsan. Sed ac lorem sollicitudin, lacinia sem eu, dictum ipsum. Pellentesque dolor sapien, imperdiet at egestas eget, gravida id turpis. Sed semper libero eget nulla placerat, sed hendrerit eros finibus. Suspendisse vitae ipsum molestie, rutrum velit vitae, aliquam massa. Etiam elementum tempor suscipit. Suspendisse vitae justo id purus sodales ultrices.

Integer sit amet metus non enim ultrices imperdiet. Mauris nunc eros, pellentesque et mauris a, blandit sollicitudin elit. Vivamus imperdiet lorem quis enim vehicula finibus. Phasellus finibus, dui eu interdum elementum, lacus tortor aliquam lectus, vitae aliquet sem nulla sit amet velit. Aenean at aliquet magna. Proin volutpat felis dolor, et ornare ligula dapibus ac. Nulla neque velit, lacinia vel sem in, hendrerit porta nisi. Vivamus hendrerit arcu ac vulputate facilisis. Duis ultricies interdum dui, efficitur pulvinar dui gravida in. Phasellus ante nisi, faucibus et tortor eget, facilisis tempus odio. Donec ut mattis quam. Morbi sem lacus, facilisis a egestas at, efficitur venenatis ipsum. Etiam ullamcorper lacus non nunc auctor cursus. Nam sed ex a sapien lacinia convallis eget sit amet augue. Suspendisse in commodo sem, vel accumsan odio.
</div>
<div class="right-bar">
  <span>My text !</span>
</div>
```